# Unable to execute a SQL LIKE query

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm getting a value as params when I make an axios GET request and I want to use that value to make an SQL query. This is the code:

````py
@app.route('/get-hcp-data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_hcp_data():
   value = request.args.get('nameValue')
   engine = connect_pg()
   sql = "select * from dim_hcp_details where hcp_name like " + value + "%"
   hcp_details = pd.read_sql_query(sql,engine)
   hcp_dict = hcp_details.to_dict()
   print(hcp_dict)
   return jsonify(hcp_dict)
``
When I press the button 'a', I'm getting this error in the terminal of Flask: 

> [SQL: select * from dim_hcp_details where hcp_name like a%]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

For reference here is the axios get request that I'm executing in the front end using ReactJS.

```javascript
fetchingDataOnChange = () => {
  let nameValue = this.state.searchName;
  console.log('Name inside fetchingdata: ', nameValue);
  axios.get('/get-hcp-data?', {
      params: {
          nameValue: nameValue,
      }
  })
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
    });
}
````

Comment: Your SQL query is not valid! Add single quotes around `" + value + "%`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution like this. First, I sent a post request instead of a get request using Axios inside my React Component like this:

```
  fetchingDataOnChange = () => {
    let nameValue = this.state.searchName;
    var myParams = {
        nameValue: nameValue
    }
    axios.post('/get-hcp-data', myParams) 
        .then((res) => {
            const hcps = res.data;
            this.setState({ hcps: hcps, hcpName: 
      Object.values(hcps.hcp_details_concat) })
       Object.values(this.state.hcps.hcp_details_concat));
            console.log(res);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

I then wrote my Flask code in this manner to get the data from axios. Used request.get_json to get every keystroke and executed a SQL query based on that.

```
 @app.route('/get-hcp-data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def get_hcp_data():
    value = request.get_json()
    newValue = value['nameValue']
    engine = connect_pg()
    sql = "select * from dim_hcp_details where lower(hcp_name) like 
    lower('"+newValue+"%') limit 50"
    hcp_details = pd.read_sql_query(sql,engine)
    hcp_details['hcp_details_concat'] = "[" + hcp_details['hcp_id'] + "]" + 
    hcp_details['hcp_name']
    hcp_dict = hcp_details.to_dict()
    return jsonify(hcp_dict)
```